# Netgear GS724T static IP assignment

Tags: ipv4, netgear-prosafe

I have a Netgear GS724T smart switch. I'm not sure if this can be done, but I want to assign a static IP address to each of the 24 ports on the switch so that any device connected to a particular port will always have the same IP address. Is that possible and if yes, please help me to configure it.

Comment: That is a layer-2 switch, so you do not assign layer-3 addresses to the interfaces. Also, assigning addresses to the switch interface has nothing to do with what address a device connected to the interface gets. A host will either be statically configured, or it will be configured by DHCP from a DHCP server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

No! You can't do that, as the comment from Ron shows.
You have to configure static IPs on your PCs or you have to configure your DHCP Server. The keyword for your DHCP Server ist "MAC Reservation".
Depending on your DHCP Server you will find suitable instruction via google.